# Math.sign(k) in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, polyfills

I've written a [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) script which runs perfectly fine in Chrome on Mac OSX. It crashes in Safari, however, writing to the console:

> TypeError: `undefined` is not a function (evaluating '`Math.sign(k)`')

Which, based on the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign), seems to not be supported yet.

On the page there is an included polyfill for this:

```
Math.sign = Math.sign || function(x) {
    x = +x; // convert to a number
    if (x === 0 || isNaN(x)) {
        return x;
    }
    return x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

But is there any other native function that would produce the same effect? When will ECMAScript 6 proposal be accepted?

Should I just be creating browser exceptions like:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
    usePolyfill();
}
```

or just use the polyfill 100% of the time?

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: At first I thought the answer was obvious. Then I started thinking about it. Now I'm really hoping an expert comes along and gives an answer (whether it's my obvious answer or not). Which choice I thought was right doesn't really matter, anymore.

Comment: Yeah, if I had to take a guess at what the de facto suggestion might be, I'd say there should be some external script containing all the polyfills. After some time, I'd just stop serving the polyfills with the source, whenever they adopt all these new standards.